# Call an external webservice from within a .NET Core Web API POST method

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I am currently creating a simple game that can be played from the Postman console, as a .NET Core Web API project.

I can POST data to the game from Postman without difficulty but I'm having some problems setting up a call to an external webservice at the point at which the POST is made.

What I want to do is receive a POST, and then make an external API call for some random numbers from an external service that provides random numbers.
This method would seem to need to be inside the POST method to ensure that it's triggered after each POST request and generates new numbers each time.

I have created a `ProcessRandomNumbers` asynchronous method using HTTPWebClient that returns a value of 'msg' (message) and then I am trying to call that method in my POST, then pars the string to numbers and assign the values and use them for calculations. However, I can't seem to access the data ('msg') returned from the method inside of my POST request?

The code inside my POST method is below:

```
    await ProcessRandomNumbers();

    if (diceRoll.Roll == true)
    {
        diceRoll.DiceRoll = msg;
    }
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Can post the code on how you call the external service and assign the response back to the msg field?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying to help!

The code is below:

`private static async Task ProcessRandomNumbers()
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");

            var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=2&min=1&max=6&col=2&base=10&format=plain");

            var msg = await stringTask;

            
        }`

Comment: looks like you are assigning value to local variable and this `msg` variable not accessible by caller method. Posted the code snippet below to give you an idea how you could implement this method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `ProcessNumbers()` only trying to get the numbers from external website, so this method can be renamed as `GetRandomNumbers()`.

Here is the code snippet where I returned the API response back to caller:

```
private async Task<string> GetRandomNumber()
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");
     return await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=2&min=1&max=6&col=2&base=10&format=plain"); 
 }
```

In the caller assign the return value to `msg` field, and use it.